# Getting error while trying to install watir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I am having trouble install Watir. I am guessing that I am missing some C libraries.
Here is what I did:

- Installed Rubyinstaller
- Installed devkit
- gem update --system
- gem install watir --platform x86-mingw32

and here is my output:

```
C:\>gem install watir --platform x86-mingw32
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:561:in `try_cpp'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `block in have_header'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1039:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection. Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What operating system are you working on?

Comment: What Ruby are you using? 32bit or 64 bit? Did you install proper version of Devkit for your Ruby? One way would be to delete Devkit directory and download the proper version and install it again with `--force` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shell install headers for *FFI* for the *MINGW* platform. If you are using *MINGW* for *CYGWIN*, you should run *CYGWIN* installer and install the **libffi-devel/libffi-dev** package. Otherwise, you should install external development package for *MINGW* like [this](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/dependencies/libffi-dev_3.0.6-1_win32.zip) to support development headers for *ffi*.

Additionally, please see here on how to use *FFI* on *mingw* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136780/ruby-ffi-on-mingw).